# Segmentaton fault for simple strcat() wrapper function

Tags: c

I have an exercise where I need to write a wrapper function for strcat.  After it prints the string length (for debugging) it seg faults and I am not quite sure why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I didn't specify that the wrapper function is supposed to guarantee that it never goes outside of the bounds of memory allocated for destination.  This is why I allocated only enough memory for "string" in destination and reallocating more in the Strcat() wrapper.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char* Strcat(char* destination, const char* source);

    int main(void)
    {
        (void)printf("This strcat cannot fail!\n");
        char* destination = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*7);
        destination = "string";
        (void)printf("%s\n", destination);
        Strcat(destination, " concatination");
        (void)printf("%s\n", destination);
        (void)printf("It works!\n");

        free(destination);

        return 0;
    }

    char* Strcat(char* destination, const char* source)
    {
        (void)printf("%d\n", (strlen(destination)+strlen(source))*sizeof(char));
        if((sizeof((strlen(destination)+strlen(source)))+1) > sizeof(destination))
            destination = (char*)realloc(destination, sizeof((strlen(destination)+strlen(source)))+1);
        return strcat(destination, source);
    }
```

Comment: Your code is really a mess! IMHO, you should improve your legibility.

Comment: You do not need the `(void)` infront of the printf.

Comment: what might you suggest to improve legibility?

Comment: The (void) casting is because -Wall -Wextra will give you a warning when compiling because printf has a return value which I intend to ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
destination = "string";
```

overwrites the pointer returned from `malloc(3)` so you lose that memory forever. You probably meant to copy that string, so use `strcpy(3)` or something.

Comment: This was the problem.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if((sizeof((strlen(destination)+strlen(source)))+1) > sizeof(destination))
```

That's wrong, sizeof doesn't give you anything comparable to the length of the string. Don't use it here.

Moreover, you can't really get the number of allocated bytes of the string. So if you know destination has been allocated with `malloc`[*], you should `realloc` unconditionally:

```
        destination = (char*)realloc(destination, strlen(destination)+strlen(source)+1);
```

Again, no sizeof. And be prepared to handle allocation failures, which means saving the old value of `destination` and freeing it when `realloc` returns 0.

[*] Note that `destination = "string"` breaks this premise.

Answer (score 0):

Try summat like

```
char *Strcat(char *d, const char *s) /* please put in the proper names - i am being lazy*
{
   int dLen = strlen(d); /* ditto above */
   int sLen = strlen(s);
   d = (char *)realloc(d, dLen + sLen +1);
   return strcat(d, s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I think this would possibly help my code look a little more legible and make it easier to follow.